# Java reads text file with extra whitespace and CRLF

Tags: java, parsing, powershell, io

I have a text file generated by PowerShell using the command

`GetChild-Item C:\Source\Path | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } > "C:\MyPlace\outfile.txt"`

This generates `outfile.txt` which opens like this Notepad++
[image: Notepad++]

but when opened in Java and read line by line like so:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    System.out.println(i + ":\t" + line);
}
```

It produces this:

[image: Java output]

Which totally garbles my processing. I've tried replacing whitespace characters but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like 2-byte characters.  Are you opening as UTF-16?

Comment: last time I saw something like that when I used utf-8 with BOM (Byte Order Mark), but helped changing encoding of file to utf-8 without BOM

Comment: BOMs make no sense with UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that Powershell is emitting a file with a unicode encoding but Java is reading it as plain old ASCII.  You need to change the java code to read the file as unicode.

Comment: +1 Yep. The two boxes at the beginning of the first line are the Unicode byte order mark.

Comment: That worked. I was opening with a `FileReader` and I changed it to `InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(myfile), "UTF16")`. Can I be safe to assume that `FileReader` is deprecated and I should use `FileInputStream`s?

Comment: @DavidB my java-fu is a bit dated so I wouldn't be the best person to answer that particular question.

Comment: @DavidB FileReader is not deprecated. But I would advise against using it until they add a constructor allowing specifying the file's encoding. Currently, it uses Java's platform default encoding.

Answer (score 4):

`>` is syntactic sugar for `Out-File` with some predefined parameter settings. One of which is the encoding. By default `Out-File` will create a file in little endian unicode. So to make the file with ASCII encoding you can do this:

```
GetChild-Item C:\Source\Path | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } | 
    Out-File "C:\MyPlace\outfile.txt" -Encoding ASCII
```

...Or you can use `Add-Content` which outputs ASCII by default:

```
GetChild-Item C:\Source\Path | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } | 
    Add-Content "C:\MyPlace\outfile.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't versed in text encoding enough to realize the difference, but I'll keep this in my toolbox.